# Firefox not showing full HTML page - CSS

Tags: html, css, firefox

I have a website with bootstrap CSS.

I tested it on chrome and edge browsers, the CSS seems perfectly fine.

On firefox, everything looks zoomed in. When i go to the settings of the browser and zoom out, I can see the full HTML.

On chrome :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aa8YE.jpg

Firefox normal size:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wv2es.jpg

Firefox zoomed out :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/BPW0f.jpg

I am completely new to CSS, any help would be appreciated.

Sample of my code: https://jsfiddle.net/hewp0q2j/

HTML

```
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<!------ Include the above in your HEAD tag ---------->


<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <div class="container app">
    <div class="row app-one">
      <div class="col-sm-4 side">
          <div class="side-one">
                    <div class="row sideBar" id="users">
                        <div class="row sideBar-body">
                               <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-3 sideBar-avatar">
                                     <div class="avatar-icon">
                                          <img src="img/user_away.png">
                                      </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-9 col-xs-9 sideBar-main">
                                      <div class="row">
                                           <div class="col-sm-8 col-xs-8 sideBar-name"> 
                                                <span class="name-meta">David Leff</span><br><span class="time-meta">Last Active 1h 51m  ago.</span>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                 </div>
                        </div>
              </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-sm-8 conversation">
        <div id="chatdiv">
           <div class="row message" id="conversation">
                       <div class="row message-body">
                            <div class="col-sm-12 message-main-receiver">
                              <div class="receiver">
                                <div class="message-text">
                                 Hi, what are you doing?!
                                </div>
                                <span class="message-time pull-right">
                                  Sun
                                </span>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>

          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row reply">
          <div class="col-sm-9 col-xs-9 reply-main">

             <textarea class="form-control" rows="1" id="comment" onkeypress="processKeyPress(event, this)"></textarea>
          </div>

          <div class="col-sm-1 col-xs-1 reply-send">
            <span onclick="SendMessage()">
                <i class="fa fa-send fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </span>
            <span class="error" id ="error"></span>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

CSS

```
html,
body,
div,
span {
/**  height: 100%;*/
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


.fa-2x {
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

.app {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 19px;
  height: calc(100% - 38px);
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .06), 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}

.app-one {
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .06), 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}

.side {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
.side-one {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  top: 0;
}

.side-two {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
  position: relative;
  top: -100%;
  left: -100%;
  -webkit-transition: left 0.3s ease;
  transition: left 0.3s ease;

}


.heading {
  padding: 10px 16px 10px 15px;
  margin: 0;
  height: 60px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #eee;
  z-index: 1000;
}

.heading-avatar {
  padding: 0;
  cursor: pointer;

}

.heading-avatar-icon img {
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
}

.heading-name {
  padding: 0 !important;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.heading-name-meta {
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 100%;
  padding: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  text-align: left;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  color: #000;
  display: block;
}
.heading-online {
  display: none;
  padding: 0 5px;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #93918f;
}
.heading-compose {
  padding: 0;
}

.heading-compose i {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
  color: #93918f;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.heading-dot {
  padding: 0;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.heading-dot i {
  text-align: right;
  padding: 5px;
  color: #93918f;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.searchBox {
  padding: 0 !important;
  margin: 0 !important;
  height: 60px;
  width: 100%;
}

.searchBox-inner {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px !important;
  background-color: #fbfbfb;
}


/*#searchBox-inner input {
  box-shadow: none;
}*/

.searchBox-inner input:focus {
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.sideBar {
  padding: 0 !important;
  margin: 0 !important;
  background-color: #fff;
  overflow-y: auto;
  border: 1px solid #f7f7f7;
  height: calc(100% - 20px);
}

.sideBar-body {
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px !important;
  /**border-bottom: 1px solid #f7f7f7;*/
  height: 72px;
  margin: 0 !important;
  /*cursor: pointer;*/
}

/*.sideBar-body:hover {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}*/

.sideBar-avatar {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0 !important;
}

.avatar-icon img {
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 49px;
  width: 49px;
}

.sideBar-main {
  padding: 0 !important;
}

.sideBar-main .row {
  padding: 0 !important;
  margin: 0 !important;
}

.sideBar-name {
  padding: 10px !important;
}

.name-meta {
  font-size: 100%;
  padding: 1% !important;
  text-align: left;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  color: #000;
}

.sideBar-time {
  padding: 10px !important;
}

.time-meta {
  text-align: right;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 1% !important;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
  vertical-align: baseline;
}

/*New Message*/

.newMessage {
  padding: 0 !important;
  margin: 0 !important;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  left: -100%;
}
.newMessage-heading {
  padding: 10px 16px 10px 15px !important;
  margin: 0 !important;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #00bfa5;
  z-index: 1001;
}

.newMessage-main {
  padding: 10px 16px 0 15px !important;
  margin: 0 !important;
  height: 60px;
  margin-top: 30px !important;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1001;
  color: #fff;
}

.newMessage-title {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 700;
  padding: 10px 5px !important;
}
.newMessage-back {
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  padding: 12px 5px !important;
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.newMessage-back i {
  margin: auto !important;
}

.composeBox {
  padding: 0 !important;
  margin: 0 !important;
  height: 60px;
  width: 100%;
}

.composeBox-inner {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px !important;
  background-color: #fbfbfb;
}

.composeBox-inner input:focus {
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.compose-sideBar {
  padding: 0 !important;
  margin: 0 !important;
  background-color: #fff;
  overflow-y: auto;
  border: 1px solid #f7f7f7;
  height: calc(100% - 160px);
}

/*Conversation*/

.conversation {
  padding: 0 !important;
  margin: 0 !important;
  height: 100%;
  /*width: 100%;*/
  border-left: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .08);
  /*overflow-y: auto;*/
}

.message {
  padding: 0 !important;
  margin: 0 !important;
  background: url("w.jpg") no-repeat fixed center;
  background-size: cover;
  overflow-y: auto;
  border: 1px solid #f7f7f7;
  height: calc(100% - 120px);
}
.message-previous {
  margin : 0 !important;
  padding: 0 !important;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
}
.previous {
  font-size: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px !important;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.previous a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.message-body {
  margin: 0px 0px 3px 0px !important;
  padding: 0 !important;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
}

.message-main-receiver {
  /*padding: 10px 20px !important;*/
  max-width: 60%;
}

.message-main-sender {
/*  padding: 3px 20px !important;*/
  margin-left: 40% !important;
  max-width: 60%;
}

.message-text {
  margin: 0 !important;
  padding: 5px !important;
  word-wrap:break-word;
  font-weight: 200;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding-bottom: 0 !important;
}

.message-time {
  margin: 0 !important;
  margin-left: 50px !important;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-align: right;
  color: #9a9a9a;

}

.receiver {
  width: auto !important;
  padding: 4px 10px 7px !important;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 0;
  background: #dae4f1;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  word-wrap: break-word;
  display: inline-block;
}

.sender {
  float: right;
  width: auto !important;
  background:  #2b4871; /**#ffdb99;**/
  color:white;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 0 10px;
  padding: 4px 10px 7px !important;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  display: inline-block;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}


/*Reply*/

.reply {
  height: 117px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #f5f1ee;
  padding: 10px 5px 10px 5px !important;
  margin: 0 !important;
  z-index: 1000;
}

.reply-emojis {
  padding: 5px !important;
}

.reply-emojis i {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px !important;
  color: #93918f;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.reply-recording {
  padding: 5px !important;
}

.reply-recording i {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px !important;
  color: #93918f;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.reply-send {
  padding: 5px !important;
}

.reply-send i {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px !important;
  color: #93918f;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.reply-main {
  padding: 2px 5px !important;
}

.reply-main textarea {
  width: 100%;
  resize: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 5px !important;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  text-indent: 5px;
  box-shadow: none;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.reply-main textarea:focus {
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  text-indent: 5px;
  box-shadow: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  .app {
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
  }
  .heading {
    height: 70px;
    background-color: #009688;
  }
  .fa-2x {
    font-size: 2.3em !important;
  }
  .heading-avatar {
    padding: 0 !important;
  }
  .heading-avatar-icon img {
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
  }
  .heading-compose {
    padding: 5px !important;
  }
  .heading-compose i {
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  .heading-dot {
    padding: 5px !important;
    margin-left: 10px !important;
  }
  .heading-dot i {
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  .sideBar {
    height: calc(100% - 130px);
  }
  .sideBar-body {
    height: 80px;
  }
  .sideBar-avatar {
    text-align: left;
    padding: 0 8px !important;
  }
  .avatar-icon img {
    height: 55px;
    width: 55px;
  }
  .sideBar-main {
    padding: 0 !important;
  }
  .sideBar-main .row {
    padding: 0 !important;
    margin: 0 !important;
  }
  .sideBar-name {
    padding: 10px 5px !important;
  }
  .name-meta {
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 5% !important;
  }
  .sideBar-time {
    padding: 10px !important;
  }
  .time-meta {
    text-align: right;
    font-size: 14px;
    padding: 4% !important;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
    vertical-align: baseline;
  }
  /*Conversation*/
  .conversation {
    padding: 0 !important;
    margin: 0 !important;
    height: 100%;
    /*width: 100%;*/
    border-left: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .08);
    /*overflow-y: auto;*/
  }
  .message {
    height: calc(100% - 140px);
  }
  .reply {
    height: 70px;
  }
  .reply-emojis {
    padding: 5px 0 !important;
  }
  .reply-emojis i {
    padding: 5px 2px !important;
    font-size: 1.8em !important;
  }
  .reply-main {
    padding: 2px 8px !important;
  }
  .reply-main textarea {
    padding: 8px !important;
    font-size: 18px;
  }
  .reply-recording {
    padding: 5px 0 !important;
  }
  .reply-recording i {
    padding: 5px 0 !important;
    font-size: 1.8em !important;
  }
  .reply-send {
    padding: 5px 0 !important;
  }
  .reply-send i {
    padding: 5px 2px 5px 0 !important;
    font-size: 1.8em !important;
  }
}
```

Comment: hey do see my answer i was posted but u deleted your post right @HelpASisterOut

Comment: @IswaryaSwaminadhan yes sorry I had to re-post the question after I discovered that after "zoom-out" I was able to see the full HTML

Comment: kk yar u just write the css like here the link i have https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1167666/How-to-Apply-CSS-HACKS-for-Different-Browsers-Chro

Comment: Could you please provide the css you are applying? 
It seems like you are not setting the height of your website the correct way.

Comment: Share your code or we can't help you. You can create a stacksnippet on the post, or use external tools like jsfiddle.net .

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude I updated my answer

Comment: @AriMirra I updated my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@HelpASisterOut you should really rethink your HTML and CSS formats. The website doesn't need to be as complicated. General styling recomendations are:

- avoid setting styles in CSS to html/body/div/span tags
- avoid repeated CSS code, use classes instead (padding, margin, etc.)
- avoid using calc() and mixes of percentages and pixels (breaks responsiveness of the page)
- think another solution (inheritance, classes, ids) instead of using !important everywhere
- avoid using overflow and setting positions manually as each browser may render different things/sizes

other things like repeating same-width bootstrap classes are unnecessary:

```
col-sm-9 col-xs-9
```

bootstrap takes the smaller one and applies to all bigger sizes.

---

This is not a direct answer and I apologize for not pointing the exact mistake, but I promise you that with this things in mind your app will be rightly rendered on all mayor browsers and even on mobile. You just need to look at things differently, maybe explore some webpages done by others. Hope this helps.
Good learning!

Comment: Actually removing the `calc()` and replacing them with percentages instead fixed the issue. I'm not sure percentages is the right practice here, since CSS is not my speciality, so your comments are welcome. Thanks for the answer.